# Reputation "bug" on new meta sites?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, meta

On meta.stackoverflow.com, I have a different reputation than stackoverflow.com.

However, on the *other* metas, my reputation is identical to the "parent" (see meta.serverfault.com, etc).

Is this intentional? If the "new" metas are going to use this method going forward, shouldn't our met.so and SO reps be combined as well?

Comment: Yes it's intentional. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As ChrisF mentionned, it is intentionnal.

The new meta site don't work like meta.stackoverflow.com. You don't gain any reputation on those site and the reputation displayed is only the mirror of the parent site.

For further information, you can read this :
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Comment: Interestingly enough, the badges behave differently. Meta sites have their own sets of badges.

Answer (score 3):

You should refer to the faq on the meta site itself, it also explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Since [The Split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange), MSO acts like a usual per site meta. And MSE (this site) serves old MSO's function.