# Option to get inbox notifications for new meta posts

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, per-site-meta

Currently, moderators get an inbox message for each new post submitted to a per-site meta they moderate, SO excluded.

I would like to have that, please.

The reason is, I like to know what's going on. I usually read all of meta anyway, when I notice that there's something new, so I figure I might as well get notified about it as soon as it happens.

And there's already a system that delivers new meta posts to certain inboxes.

(This might not be a good idea for MSO in particular though, at least until [the possible split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).)

Comment: This *sounds* like a good idea, probably right up until you have it. There are a lot of boring and uninteresting questions on Meta, like "why has my account been banned even though I only posted 5 spam responses--I promise to do better next time!" and "why has this question been closed/deleted?"

Comment: @CodyGray I guess that depends on which meta you're looking at. Obviously nobody would subscribe to MSO as it is. Looking at [the first page of this one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1&sort=newest), I can see a grand total of 2 uninteresting "where did this question/my rep go" type questions. And those are to be expected really, because an entire tag was recently purged, along with 600(!) questions.