# Is the "all-sites" tag necessary?

Tags: support, tags, meta

I see there are 52 questions tagged [all-sites](/questions/tagged/all-sites), which seems used for saying that the issue is for all the sites.

Is there really any difference if the question is about two/three sites, or it is about all the sites? Since all the sites but Area 51 use the same base code, if the bug is not an issue in the CSS styles, then it is probable the bug is present in all the Stack Exchange sites. Just in the case the code is being tested on this very site, the bug is not visible on other sites.

The tag has been first used on a question dated 2009, and there are other questions using that tag dated 2010, 2011, and 2012. It is not a tag that has been recently introduced.

Comment: Seems like this'll be solved *if* [Meta SE / Meta SO split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124015/135887).

Comment: @Charles that's been "6 to 8 weeks" for over a year now - I don't see those changes actually happening any time soon, making this  question still very relevant. Should the switch ever happen, this could simply be closed and archived as "historical" (or more likely just deleted).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are now <del>117</del> 57 questions tagged [all-sites](/questions/tagged/all-sites). I'm going to edit them over the next few days to remove the tag. Anyone else is free to join me on this endeavour.

Actually now that I've started this (a few at a time to avoid flooding the homepage), I wonder whether merging [all-sites](/questions/tagged/all-sites) with [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) is not a better idea. The wiki for the latter states:

> This tag is for questions about the entire network of Q&A sites that make up the Stack Exchange network.

which covers what [all-sites](/questions/tagged/all-sites) means and will mean that the tag gets removed without bumping some really old questions. I've suggested the synonym so votes and or a moderator merging would be appreciated.

All that's then needed is someone with moderator access to come along and mark the question as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: the synonym does look like a good idea, voted. I'd argue that the stackexchange tag on meta.SE is redundant, but there are 1300 questions tagged like that, so it won't get removed by users like us anyway.

Comment: My suggestion would be that if you delete this tag from a post and you don't have enough reputation to edit, include a reference to this thread as part of the edit suggestion. Otherwise reviewers who haven't landed here might not understand why a seemingly invalid edit is occurring.

Comment: I presume there is no way to avoid bumping by our editing manually? There is currently an edit suggestion for this very thing, and wonder if approval will bump the question (rejection seems unfair based on "will bump the question")

Comment: @James - any manual edit will bump the post. That's why I, belatedly, thought of adding the synonym and getting a CM to merge the tags.

Comment: What about quickly mass editing them. Would only take 10 mins for even one person to do the lot. Then suck it up that the front page is flooded with them, and over the space of (an hour or so?) the front page will recover? There is not need for a synonym at all, as "all sites" is what MSE is about, no tag needed for that. Then we can get rid of "all-sites" completely without needing synonym.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ you can carry on editing if you want. I'm holding out for the synonym.

Comment: I haven't started. It's not an urgent or highly problematic issue, so waiting for a better resolve than flooding front page :)