# Is there a need for the [stackexchange] tag on this site?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange, meta

I suspect that [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) is a relic of the days when this was a dual-purpose site, functioning as a Meta site for both Stack Exchange as a whole and Stack Overflow individually. Now that it no longer has that role, the tag seems to be redundant. Should it be removed?

Comment: Good idea. First we better find all questions that got only this tag, e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286348/are-there-plans-for-metrics-associated-with-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-ex), and retag so that the tag removal won't leave questions without any "real" tag.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126507/147191.

Comment: Well, according to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/573440/get-questions-with-only-a-specific-tag-plus-bug-feature-request-support-discussi?tag=stackexchange), there are 225 questions with that tag only. Not trivial to retag all of them, we'll need a team effort.

Comment: @zaq sure, but I don't think we should deliberately do this to questions, I believe that any question better have an actual tag.