# When will MSO get rebranded into the meta for all SE sites?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

I was told by a moderator that at some point, MSO will become more like other meta sites (same rep on main and meta, scope constrained to issues with main site only).  I was just curious what the plans were on this and when it was expected to happen.

Comment: It's being split into MSO and MSE. 6-8 weeks (I think MSE will retain rep)

Comment: If anyone answers with 6-8 weeks, I will glare at them through the Internet.

Comment: so what will be happen to my account ? will it get deleted from here ?

Comment: @luc details, details.. I think you get to keep rep for non-SO posts on MSE. MSO will probably share rep with SO..

Comment: ok fine @TimManishEarth

Comment: @Lucifer last time I heard they said after the split all MSO users under 10K will be banned and suspended. Time is [running out](http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php "How long is it going to take?")

Comment: Wait @TimManishEarth - do you mean 6-8 weeks as in http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php ?

Comment: @Scott. Nope. See second answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta

Comment: @scott oh, that _is_ the same thing :p

Comment: @Tim ManishEarth: What's wrong with you? 6-8 weeks is 6-8 weeks no matter where or what it is.

Comment: you mean my account will be closed ? @gnatakaspecialagentMulder

Comment: @bolt yeah, the page didn't open for me. I realized later :/

Comment: @Lucifer I was just kidding

Comment: ohh.. Thank God, I was very worried that i need to start from 1 reputation again. BTW, it was nice joke :P @gnatakaspecialagentMulder