# Why is a link to Meta Stack Overflow shown on each Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, meta, per-site-meta

Why is a link to http://meta.stackoverflow.com displayed in the footer of *every* Stack Exchange site (e.g. [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [sceptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/))?

I mean, every Stack Exchange site has its own meta site, so why is http://meta.stackoverflow treated so specially? Shouldn't it be visible only on http://stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Well, it's not part of the footer on beta sites like [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) and [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). I'd guess the footer only lists other sites within the same beta/non-beta category. So Meta is not that special after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta SO is also the global Meta for general network-wide SO/SE issues which are not specific to a single Q&A within the network.

If you look at the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) it states:

> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange
> - Stack Overflow Careers
> - Promotions &
>     Advertising Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core
>     Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites …
>
> it is welcome here.

So it's not merely for questions about Stack Overflow. 
There will however be a separate Meta for Stack Overflow [at some point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).

Comment: But then why is there no link to meta.gaming.stackexchange.com on gaming.stackexchange.com, for instance? There is a link to "hot topics" on the meta site, but that takes me directly to some question or other, not to the list of questions.

Comment: All site-specific metas can be accessed directly using the dropdown menu at the top.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding one more point to answer of Bart.

Currently all feature request, bug reporting, Promotions & Advertising Support is done on Meta StackOverflow. Hence it is shown on all site's footer. But this will be replaced in near future with [MetaStackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Please see [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: `Currently all feature request, bug reporting, Promotions & Advertising Support is done on Meta StackOverflow` -> not true. Bug reports, feature requests posted on per-site metas are handled there as well. Site promos are almost exclusively done on per-site metas

Comment: @Sathya: But this documentation is done only for MSO and not any other meta site. Do you have any official references which proves we can add bug reports to other meta site?

Comment: um. as a Moderator on another SE site I'm telling you this. The team's also explicitly made it clear it's fine to post feature requests & bug reports on per-site metas.