# I don't see the user account I have in a meta site, under the list of my accounts

Tags: support, linked-accounts, per-site-meta

[Write a code golf problem in which script languages are at a major disadvantage](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/547/write-a-code-golf-problem-in-which-script-languages-are-at-a-major-disadvantage#7243) was originally on Code Golf, but it was moved over to its meta site.

When I look under my Stack Overflow profile, I don't see that account in the list of my accounts.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Only meta.stackoverflow gets its own "account". All others are don't.

Comment: So, you mean to say that the accounts on meta aren't linked with my SE account? That doesn't make sense. But thank you for your response. If you'll submit an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: meta.SO is the only meta that has it's own separate rep system. All the other metas just use the rep from the host account on the main site. So there's no point in having a separate entry in that list.

Comment: Code Golf Meta is _not_ a separate site, it's an extension of Code Golf, that's why there's no link to it on your SO profile. Meta SO is the _only_ Meta that's a separate site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, meta.stackoverflow is the only meta site that has its own rep system. All the other meta sites just use the rep from the host account on the main site.

So in that sense, there's no point having a separate entry in your accounts list for that.

However, [this is planned to change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).

Answer (score 2):

The pages listing the accounts you have on Stack Exchange sites don't show the accounts you have in their meta sites; those pages just list the accounts in the main sites.

The only exception is Meta Stack Overflow, which is the meta site for Stack Overflow, but also the meta site for the Stack Exchange network. It is also the only meta site with its own reputation, while other meta sites have a reputation that is linked to the main site reputation. (In other words, on Meta Stack Overflow, you gain reputation for posts you have there, while this doesn't happen in other meta sites.) That is the reason why it gets listed together the other Stack Exchange sites, even if it is a meta site.