# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a link to the meta user?

Tags: support, meta

On other Stack Exchange sites, a user profile contains a link to the meta user.

[image: Drupal Answers]

Why doesn't the same link appear on Stack Overflow?

[image: Stack Overflow]

Was recently removed, or was always been so?

Comment: There have been a number of feature requests for this: e.g., http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143550/stack-overflow-mso-profiles-should-have-main-meta-profile-links and its duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always been this way, because the relationship between Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow is different than the one between per-site metas and their parent sites (on many levels, but specifically on a technical one).

Adding such a link between Stack Overflow and this site would require special casing this oddball relationship, and I imagine it just hasn't made sense to do so. I'd have to double-check the proposed implementation, but it's possible this will resolve itself once the network-level Meta splits off into its own entity and Stack Overflow gets a "proper" per-site meta.

Comment: I hadn't heard about this project to split meta between a proper meta.stackoverflow and what I understand as a meta.stackexchange. Is there a presentation somewhere ?

Comment: I right noticed something that would make it hard to implement the same link on Stack Overflow: on Drupal Answers, my user ID is both 199; on Stack Overflow, my user ID is different from the user ID I have on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dystroy See [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124015)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Right, all other sites on the network share users between their main and meta sites, whereas Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow are completely separate except by name.