# meta SO listed in user accounts however none of the other metas are listed

Tags: support, meta, user-accounts

Why is it that only meta SO is listed as one of my accounts in SE. Whereas the other meta's such as meta super user, meta dba's, meta cross-val are not listed? Is it because the meta SO is different from the rest in that it is also the meta for SE ? or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because meta.SO *is* a separate account, unlike the other metas, which are coupled to your account on the related main site. You'll notice that on other site metas your reputation is the same as the main site, and you don't gain/lose reputation there for questions/answers etc.

Comment: Oh thanks that I never noticed. Is there a reason for this change between metas?

Comment: @Sai - I believe that SO meta had been around for some time before the other metas were implemented.

Comment: Right, and there is a subtle difference, meta.SO is a place to discuss the main SO site as well as the entire network. I believe there are plans to split those out. *Someday*. A per-site meta is where you discuss issues that are relevant only to that site.

Comment: Ok that is understandable. thanks :)

Comment: Although you might not have intended it but the answer seems to suggest that meta.SO isn't coupled to the main site. Right?

Comment: @hus787 meta.SO is the meta site for ALL sites in the entire StackExchange network. Stack Overflow currently doesn't have its own per-site meta, but it should, and [there is ongoing work in this area](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).