# Why do I see questions regarding other Stack Exchange sites on here?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, scope

From my understanding... doesn't every Stack Exchange site have its own meta? I sometimes see questions about other Stack Exchange sites. Is it because SO is one of the first ones? What exactly is the policy on asking questions regarding other sites? Just wondering.

Comment: "doesn't every StackExchange site have its own meta?" We'll have one in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Relatedish: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [About](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page:

> This site is for meta-discussion of the **Stack Exchange family** of Q&A websites.

Comment: @aug Each site has its own Meta to handle site-specific issues. Currently, Meta Stack Overflow serves as the global Meta for issues that potentially relate to all sites on the network, in addition to its own site-specific issues.

Comment: Completely missed that... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @animuson thanks for that! I deleted my comment because I had a sudden epiphany haha... but I do appreciate that clarification :)