# Is there a tag for site-specific close reasons?

Tags: support, tags, meta

I now understand the difference between the [flagging-dialog](/questions/tagged/flagging-dialog), [close-dialog](/questions/tagged/close-dialog), and [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) tags, but it's not clear to me what tag(s) is/are associated with site-specific close reasons.

Does [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) cover all the site-specific reasons? If not, is there a tag for SO-specific close reasons?

Comment: Site-specific reasons for sites other than SO should be directed at their own meta. Close-reasons here should core SO & network-wide ones.

Comment: I thought MSO was the meta for all of SE. Does each site have their own meta now?

Comment: They all have (since forever pretty much) except Stack Overflow. And that's going to be fixed some day. MSO is for SO + SE-wide issues.

Comment: Ah, so they do. Thanks. Didn't realize that. Do you know if MSO (or the meta of SO) will continue to host SE-wide issues as well as SO-specific meta issues?

Comment: There are plans to separate Meta-SO and Meta-SE. Comes up every now and again. (e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: @Mat That idea is at the "seems good but would be a __lot__ of work" stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site-specific issues should be discussed on the [per-site Meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/). This is linked from the main site in the top navigation bar, or if you're into URL manipulation follows the format:

```
http://meta.sitename.stackexchange.com/
```

That will put you directly in touch with not only the moderators on that site, but also that site's *community*. Most people who are active on only one or two sites do not regularly troll Meta Stack Overflow.

The only things you would need to bring up here would be:

- Issues with close reasons that are *global* (i.e. affect all sites on the Stack Exchange network), in which case you've already got the run-down of the appropriate tags.
- Stack Overflow-specific issues (since this also functions as the per-site Meta for Stack Overflow). These questions should *also* have the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag added to them.