# Add Meta Stack Overflow to the list of meta sites in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, meta, android-app

- App version: 0.1.21
- Select "All sites"
- Tap the "Main sites" dropdown and switch it to "Meta sites"
- Meta Stack Overflow is not on the list; searching by typing "stack" returns an empty list.

It does appear on the list of "Main sites".

Can you please add it to the list of meta sites as well, instead or in addition to the list of main sites?

Comment: This Meta is unique among all other meta sites and is actually a main site by all means, with its own users, reputation etc. So I believe that's correct and by design.

Comment: Well, it **isn't** a "classic" child meta. It is used both for Stack Overflow and the entire Stack Exchange network, has its own reputation system and more. I am not on the mobile team, but this is most probably [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: Post-alpha app users may not appreciate the difference.

Comment: Maybe a fair compromise would be including it in both lists.

Comment: @TomG - How so? It is different from other Meta sites, hence, it is on not on the list of Meta sites. FWIW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange

Comment: @Oded on the surface, it "looks" like the other meta sites - it's called Meta, it has a link the same spot as the other metas, etc.   By the principle of least astonishment, an app user might expect it to act like the other metas, even if aware the quirk of history (as Jeff put it in the question you linked) that makes it different from the other sites.

Comment: @Oded Tom got a point here in my opinion. Tom, I don't think it's a bug though, maybe better change this into feature request asking to add Stack Overflow meta to the list of meta sites even though behind the scenes it's a main site. As a bug, it will be most likely just tagged as [meta-tag:status-bydesign] and be buried. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd tag changed.   Always a fine line between bugs in the code and bugs in the spec :-)

Comment: Cheers @Tom, took the liberty to edit even further in order to make what I think is a proper feature request. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://meta.stackoverflow is itself a community and has been since the time when Jeff realized that people needed a place to talk about the network of sites.  It's not a "child" meta - these are specifically to facilitate the operation of each individual community that forms around a topic.

Comment: Why was the name kept "meta stackoverflow" instead of renaming to "meta stackexchange"?

Comment: For historical reasons mostly.  There has been discussion of a split in the past here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange

Comment: Thanks. It seems to imply there's still a rename/change coming _in the future_.