# How did this site come to serve more than one purpose?

Tags: discussion

On one hand, this site is the meta site for "stack overflow."

On the other hand, this site seems to be the meta site for the rest of SE, or at least the other SE meta sites. I joined this site in the latter capacity when one of my questions on another meta site was redirected here.

At the very least, this site seems to be a meta site for other things than "stack overflow."

Is my observation correct, and if so, how and why did this come about.

Answer (score 6):

It came about because SO was the first site.  Once upon a time all questions about the entire site and all questions about just SO were one and the same.  When new sites were created, nobody bothered to create a new site-agnostic meta.  At this point, the inertia involved in trying to separate out the question base makes changing this prohibitively expensive.  [The team has been trying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange) for a year and a half now, but are, as of yet, unsuccessful in creating two sites to separate the two scopes.

Comment: I once worked at the corporate headquarters for a chain of retail stores. One of the retail stores happened to be in the same town as the headquarters, so it became the default beta tester for all of the programs, policies and technologies that were under consideration for the entire chain. Over time, it became a weird mix of new, old, and custom solutions and never quite matched the other stores. Meta SO sometimes feels like that.