# We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why is that in the Ask Question part of Meta?

> [image: screenshot]

I mean, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is one of the 4 mandatory tags of meta. Don't you think it can discourage new Meta users that want to discuss something that might be important or good for the site?

There is already a different version of this box on Stack Overflow so I think it might be a good idea to keep that part out of the Meta sites.

If the response is positive, can we please change that.

Comment: They copied it from the main site with no care.

Comment: "Don't you think it can discourage new Meta users that want to discuss something" No, I don't.  I *wish* this could stop them.  (So that it could work on every non-meta site.)

Comment: @Servy I don't understand what you mean by that. Also you cut the sentence where it said "something that might be important".

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd My point was that people don't let that message stop them from posting discussions.  Not that it shouldn't be removed anyway, of course.

Comment: New site proposal: Meta-Meta Stack Overflow -- the site where we discuss meta stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Discussion is a large part of MSO and discussions happen regularly, at the *same time* we **prefer** questions that can be answered.

I think the two can go hand in hand quite comfortably.

That signifies to people MSO prefers questions which can be answered, and don't favour any old discussion like a forum. From this users may perhaps consider rewording the question they were going to post to allow for more direct answers.
Which benefits them and us, really.

> Don't you think it can discourage new Meta users that want to discuss something that might be important or good for the site ?

Yes it has that danger, but it's not really strong enough to scare [many] people off, it's pretty tame using the word "prefer".

Also, I agree with pushing a little bit that while discussions are welcomed, MSO is still a Q&A style site and discussions should be in a Q&A structure as much as possible. Otherwise people would possibly have at it in a forum style approach.

I think at worst, they re-word their question a bit less *discussiony* and more *answerable*..

Comment: You see, my current question cannot be answered. It asks for opinion and point of view. The opposite of Q/A style. **I don't think we don't prefer questions like this one**. I really think they have their place here (meta) just as much as feature requests or bug reports. It's one of the concepts that I like the most about this specific website.

Comment: You asked a question and I answered it, and within a Q&A style permissible by MSO. I think you're pushing the Q&A style beyond its definition and certainly beyond the scope of what all Stack sites are. To a certain degree, even a lot of the answers on Stack Overflow are opinion based. "Why does this code not work" "Because of this" is not opinion based, however there are many ways to approach an issue in coding or request for coding solution, with multiple options of functions, arrays, loops, etc, and how one lays them out on the page. So it can be opinion as to how to deal with a problem.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd There is a big difference between a direct answer as happened here with me and you, ie Q&A, and a general discussion with people chatting and voicing opinions uncontrollably like in a forum.

Answer (score -2):

The "end goal" of an SE question is a definitive answer.

The site was begun by (and for) computer programmers that want answers that are ["Turing complete."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete)

"Discussion" is accepted as part of the question and answer process, but is not considered an end in itself. This is the view of a group of people that are wary of "infinite loops."

Hende, the preference for "answerability" over "discussability."

Comment: This answer seems to miss the point that the question is asking specifically about **meta**.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @mo: For historical reasons, this is more than just the meta site for stack overflow. That is, it serves more than one purpose. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196491/how-did-this-site-come-to-serve-more-than-one-purpose

Comment: The fact that this *site* can be used to discuss multiple sites doesn't change the fact that this *question* is specifically about **meta**. From the first line of the question, emphasis mine: "Why is that in the Ask Question part of **Meta**?". It's also missing the point that the original asker understands why that message would be there for SO itself, but is suggesting perhaps it should be removed from meta.

Comment: @TomAu My guess is that you read only part of my question.