# Spreading the word about the MSO-MSE-split

Tags: discussion, information-display, mso-mse-split

Personally, I logged onto Meta Stack Overflow for the first time in a few days today and was extremely confused at first as evident by the revisions to [my question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250054/mso-mse-split-confusion). I guess if I had looked around at the recent questions I could have caught on, but regardless I was quite confused.

I would have appreciated some sort of update email sent out to all linked emails of MSO accounts or at least some sort of obnoxious message that you had to read before you could proceed to MSO and use the new site. Obviously this was move was a lot to handle for the staff at Stack Exchange, but I wish I had been more informed.

Migrations like this don't occur too often, but how could something like this be done differently in the future? What do you think?

**Update:** The following banner was added to the top of every page (I think) on MSO, but this question as posed beforehand:

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of emails..

Comment: I'm sure it's nothing compared to the tag-subscription emails though.

Comment: True, but that's on a subscription basis.

Answer (score 25):

You'll be informed. There's a blog post ready to go out tomorrow morning, *early*, and it'll be linked to EVERYWHERE.

This was a lot of work on the part of a lot of people, especially Tim who has been the driving force behind actually keeping things moving in this direction after [TWO FRIGGIN' YEARS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange) of nothing happening.

So I think we can grant him and our hard-working development team a few hours of sleep before he has to push that announcement out... and deal with the response to it.

Comment: Yes, I understand the man hours that probably went into this for everyone at Stack Exchange (especially Tim) and I understand that it is unreasonable to expect everything to run smoothly (though it mostly did), but as a user I just wish I had known beforehand about this whole process.

Comment: @Wold There was a meta post on the then-MSO. We also put up a system message on the now-MSO to point folks to it for an explanation.

Comment: Maybe, an Inbox notification should also help - just like we get for Moderator elections...