# Community♦ has gone crazy on Code Review meta

Tags: bug, community-user, mso-mse-split

The [Community♦](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user on Code Review meta has had a strange behaviour recently:

- First of all, it has 5 reputation instead of 1.
- Thirty minutes ago, it felt that it was a good idea to update 91 questions at once. Right now, the "active questions" page is totally meaningless since there are only old questions in a somewhat random order.
- It removed some inline tags in some answers ([example](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1696/revisions), "[teaching](/questions/tagged/teaching)" -> "teaching") while it did not removed them in the questions.

Has it gone crazy?

#### EDIT:

Including screenshots: 
[image: CommunityUser Profile - 5 Rep]

---

[image: Active Page of CR-Meta after edit-rampage]

Comment: We saw some silly behaviour from Community on Stack Overflow Meta too; some script or other has been run to edit stuff and there are bugs in that script.

Comment: Related: [Community ♦ bot doesn't like markdown?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230288/community-bot-doesnt-like-markdown)

Comment: Seems to be happening all across the network.

Comment: Updating that many questions if fine, but breaking markdown is not.

Comment: This may or may not have been a secret plot by Code Golf. >:D

Comment: @Doorknob Have you guys gone all evil? :p

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230328/162102  The script wasn't supposed to bump questions, apparently, but had a bug.

Answer (score 12):

Community has been doing mass-updates of posts changing links that used to point to meta.stackoverflow.com, and replacing them with links to meta.stackexchange.com

The effect, for example, can be seen in [Community's activity: Migration of MSO links to MSE links](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all)

Comment: Where do the 5 rep come from, though? And why did it replace all the markdown with html-formatting?

Comment: @Vogel612 Perhaps two of the edits it made was actually approved?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Community is a mod.. the edits don't move into the review-queue.. also Community owns all edits by anonymous users, and still has 1 rep with multiple 100k edit-suggestions approved...