# Last-activity link from main is wrong for Community edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, community-user, bump

A few hours ago Community came through [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) to update MSO links to MSE (thanks!).  However, the last-modified links on the main page don't link to the posts that Community edited; they link to the question (even though the edits were in answers).  Links for answers that were posted or edited by other users work correctly.

At the time of this post the following links are behaving this way (obviously this data can be deprecated by other changes to the affected questions):

[Mi Yodeya min HaTorah minayin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26446/mi-yodeya-min-hatorah-minayin/?lastactivity)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22994/under-what-conditions-may-a-jew-participate-in-the-biblical-hermeneutics-se-site/?lastactivity
[Does anyone know where one can buy a hebrewbooks harddrive?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/does-anyone-know-where-one-can-buy-a-hebrewbooks-harddrive/?lastactivity)
[The Fanatic Badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/the-fanatic-badge/?lastactivity)

[image: question list]

Comment: +1 for the freehand red circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in the codepath that prevented bumps - when answers were edited the setting to not bump got ignored (questions did not get bumped).

The codepath has been fixed and deployed since, but unbumping is not simple to do.

Comment: Thanks.  No need to unbump (at least for us it was only four questions, no big deal); I was just puzzled by the links not working the way I expected.

Comment: I just checked our meta; on *main* there were only four bumps, but Community pwns our meta front page right now.  Oh well; it'll pass. :-)