# Is Community ♦ supposed to have 1 rep?

Tags: bug, reputation, per-site-meta, community-user

After finding [Community♦ has gone crazy on Code Review meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230290/), I thought about inspecting Community's ♦ profiles. What did I notice? Community ♦ have more than 1 rep on some **meta** sites.

- [Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - 5 rep
- [Information Security Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - 3 rep
- [User Experience Meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - 3 rep
- [Signal Processing Meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - 3 rep

Why is it?

Comment: @TravisJ Not a duplicate. That question is about an one-off thing that happened 3 years ago. Might be related, but I wouldn't call this new question close-worthy on account of that other one.

Comment: @AdamLear - So Community got reputation in this scenario from somewhere other than edits? Note that each instance is either +2 or +4 from 1.

Comment: @TravisJ There are no suggested edits on child meta sites.

Comment: @TravisJ Suggested edits aren't allowed on per-site metas.

Comment: @AdamLear - Meta rep is derived from the relative main sites though. So any rep on meta would have been earned on the related parent site.

Comment: @TravisJ Possibly. If that were the case, though, I'd expect main site's Community user to also have the same amount of rep. Or any suggested edits associated with that profile. Neither is the case. Point being, calling this a dupe is hasty. Even if it were, we need to fix this and a closure isn't helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. Redacted my vote. Related: [Eeeek! "Community" user got sudden rep boost.. how come?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come)

Comment: Why does it matter???

Comment: @PM77-1 Because it is by design. Community always have 1 rep. And now we see a bug.

Comment: So? How that effects you or anybody else? Why do you even care? Seems to me like a completely frivolous concern.

Comment: @PM77-1 It is a BUG. I reported.

Comment: You still have not answered my question.  Be it a bug,  a feature,  or whatever else,  why should we care?  Where is the real impact on this site?

Comment: @PM77-1 *You*, of course, shouldn't. I care because I don't want people to be confused. Heh, of course, it is not an impact. Simply it doesn't work as it should. But *we* care. Please read above comments, from Adam Lear. You guess who is he?

Comment: @nicael You are leaving something out of your equation. You think you are saving people from being confused, but what you really end up doing is wasting a lot of people's valuable time with issues that don't matter and nobody cares about --- and in this case is already documented anyway for anybody that does care. If you want to help, spend more time reading up and learning about the things that _do_ work rather than worrying so much about the ones you think don't.

Comment: I mostly just want to make sure there isn't a bug hiding here somewhere. Overall, this is insanely low priority and we might not actually get around to it for a while, if ever.

Comment: Can we please make a point of not assailing people for reporting a bug? It's a bug, it got reported, it matters because it's a bug - at least enough to be reported.

Comment: For those not voting to reopen, please take note of the comments at the top of this chain.  For each of the cases, the Community user has rep on a child meta site that does not derive from the main site, therefore it is impossible that it is due to Community "earning" rep via suggested edits.

Comment: How is it not a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230290/community-has-gone-crazy-on-code-review-meta

Comment: So? I read it already and wrote about at the beginning of my question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Actually... you can suggest *tag wiki* edits on per-site metas. That *might* be it.

Comment: [`[status-partially-completed?]`](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/2491/3690)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Why is the community user locked at one reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278351/why-is-the-community-user-locked-at-one-reputation)*.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in the system where Community collects a little bit of rep for some unspecified reason.

I recently asked a duplicate version of this question on [DBA.SE's Meta site](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2491/72091)<sup>1</sup>. As you can see from one of dev's answer they removed the rep manually:

> We try to never let the bots earn rep, but this one became sentient. I challenged Community to a battle of epic proportions and removed the extra 4 reputation by force. Lesson learned: never trust robots

I assume that will be needed (manual intervention) to revert the other Meta Community members back to 1 rep.

---

1: I wasn't aware of this question when I posted my duplicate question.