# How did the community user gain rep?

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta, community-user

I thought the community user was locked at one rep, but [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), it says the community user had three rep on meta unix and linux. See this: [Why is the community user locked at one reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278351/why-is-the-community-user-locked-at-one-reputation) There, the comments and answers say that the community user can't gain rep. How did this happen despite it being locked at one rep?

Comment: I  know that it's looked at one rep also because  [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57500/told-ive-been-asking-too-many-questions-and-put-on-reviews) question is owned by the community user,  is not a wiki, and I upvoted it and the community user didn't gain any rep.

Comment: Another strange thing is that the main account has a score of 1.  That makes *two* things that should keep Community at 1 on meta.

Comment: I suspect sockpuppetry. We've long feared that Community has attained sentience, a network of socks is a logical step in her attempt to take over the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the meta account got out of sync with the main account (which probably got some rep - which can happen for various reasons).

I resynced the users.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this status-completed (even though this isn't a feature request)

Comment: It isn't a bug either. We don't really tag things that are not bugs or feature requests with status tags.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me!

Comment: How else would they get out of sync?