# Should we unbugger the changes Community has just made, or will they be automatically fixed?

Tags: discussion, community-user, mso-mse-split

So, as some users have noticed, Community has just gone mad on meta sites:

- [Community♦ has gone crazy on Code Review meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230290/community-has-gone-crazy-on-code-review-meta)
- [Community ♦ bot doesn't like markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230288/community-bot-doesnt-like-markdown)

Should we (users of meta sites) fix any dumb changes it has made (mentioned in the posts linked above), or will there be an automated fix deployed at some point?

Comment: I don't think  we could revert **all** the dumb changes made, especially on larger metas. on CR alone it's 91 changes, SU has about 300, and I don't want to think about all the other meta-sites. Let the dust settle a bit, and then we'll see.

Comment: I've rolled back one edit, where the edit was clearly wrong altogether. The bot is trying to update URLs from MSO to MSE, but is a) changing URLs that don't need changing, and b) is using the HTML rendering instead of the Markdown source as a base. The former mistakes can and should be fixed; the latter should probably be 'repaired'. But that can also be done by a dev, and probably will be done by a dev.

Comment: The bot has edited about 5000 posts on MSE alone!

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1993369#1993369 :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These will be automatically fixed, over several hours today.

Comment: You broke, you fix? ;)

Comment: I broke, I fix.