# Some question titles get cut off by the right margin here on Meta

Tags: bug, design, meta

In Chrome 34.0.1847.116, on Windows 7, when I go to this question: [Should we unbugger the changes Community has just made, or will they be automatically fixed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230292/should-we-unbugger-the-changes-community-has-just-made-or-will-they-be-automati), I see the following:

[image: "automatically" cut off]

As you can see, the "y" in "automatically" in the title is partially cut off.

Comment: Also repro'd on FF 28.0, Windows XP SP 3.

Comment: It looks fine in mac os, but when zooming out 70 to 90%, this issue happens.

Comment: I can repro that only on Chrome 34.0.1847.116, Win 7 x64, **but not** on FF28 and IE11

Comment: @Vogel612 Ah, totally is, thanks.

Comment: Gotta love automatic "related" questions in the sidebar. Which is also bugged btw. But there's already a question up for that too ;)