# User who voted a Q as dupe is missing from list of users in the review. & Weird Community edits

Tags: discussion, review, edits, community-user

Both my questions here are about the same Question in question, so kept them in this one Question (err..if that makes sense)

The relevant question:
[How to refer to your blog when answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering)

**Question 1)**
Just voted for the question to be marked as dupe.
On the question itself it's shown as marked dupe by:
Al E., cVplZ, doppelgreener, gnat, James

In the [review area](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/31965) it shows the users as per above (plus one who voted Leave Open), except gnat who is not listed in the review area as having reviewed/voted on it.

What's the reason for this?
(Apart from gnat being a review ninja)

**Question 2)**
The [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/20531/revisions) for that question shows it's changed a fair bit over time, however why has *Community♦* seemingly fixed it's own fixes?

I get the first change, where it "*migrated MSO links to MSE links*" following the change over, but then twice it "*Fixed bad MSO links to MSE links migration*".

I can only surmise that it being done by a script, the changes from the first fix caused a change in condition so something else was done on the next pass over by the scripts..?
If so, shouldn't the title be different for each fix, or the scripts improved so it catches both issues in one pass over?
Maybe neither above options are possible, or necessary, I just wondered why and if there was perhaps some bug or oversight.

Comment: Regarding question 1: Maybe Gnat did not cast his vote from the review queue but directly when visiting the question?

Comment: Gnat must've voted on the post *directly* rather than in the queue.

Answer (score 7):

1. Gnat voted on the post *directly*, not in the queue. As such he didn't review the votes, he just cast one.
2. Shortly after the MSO-MSE split, the devs ran a script to migrate links from `http://meta.stackoverflow.com` to `http://meta.stackexchange.com` where appropriate, all over the Stack Exchange network. The first revisions of that script had problems so subsequent patchings-up were needed.

   All changes made by the script are attributed to Community User.

   See [Should we unbugger the changes Community has just made, or will they be automatically fixed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230292/should-we-unbugger-the-changes-community-has-just-made-or-will-they-be-automati)

Comment: 1) Fair enough cheers. I learn something new about the vote/flag system everyday. Wouldn't it be useful when reviewing to also see details of votes from directly in the question?  2) Logical, although the two Community use edits with identical titles are within 3 mins of each other. Thanks for the link, will take a looksie

Comment: @James: multiple runs were made. Some close together.

Comment: @James: but Gnat *did not review*, so why would the review record need to show he did? You already can deduce that he didn't because he's not in the review record!

Comment: Fair enough. Main point is it's not an issue.

Comment: "*also see details of votes from directly in the question*" - not add his direct vote into the review queue, as if he reviewed, but show the votes with the other reviewers. After looking at the question revisions and seeing Shog9 had once re-opened, I wondered if it should be duped or not. Had I known someone like gnat had also voted to mark as dupe, it would have added some weight to my decision - still be my own decision, had I disagreed with gnat I would have rejected, but as I was going to approve, his vote confirmed I was probs right. It's not a necessity, just maybe useful.

Comment: Your vote should stand on its own. If you ever reach a gold dupe hammer badge, you don't have anyone else to hide behind! And I don't always agree with gnat about dupes either.

Comment: Yeah your're right. We can all be wrong at times, or just *disagree*. As said, I go based on my own thoughts and decisions, and never by the majority or who specifically voted, In this case, as a prime example, I had decided *approve as dupe* was correct, just seeing someone else who's done a fair bit of reviewing agree with my decision removes *some* element of uncertainty before I push the button (which I would have anyway).

Comment: correct. For the sake of completeness, I stumbled upon the question in the queue, then decided to take a closer look at it, opened it separately and voted from outside of the queue. Guess I missed one step towards golden review badge because of that but somehow, I don't mind, I have enough of these

Comment: @gnat fair enough. I don't do reviews (or anything really) for badges, just to help the site. It's just the easiest place to do it (unless already on the question)

Comment: @James yeah, that was the case when it was simply easier to vote from outside of queue, since I was already on the question