# Question Points bouncing around

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, user-interface, hot-questions

So I was looking at this [hilarious question](https://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster) on Super User when I noticed that the points were going up/down up/down constantly. I asked if anyone else was seeing this they did and thought it seemed weird so I thought I would bring it here.

> [image: Point Bouncing]

Any clue why this is happening?

UPDATE:This behavior has been happening for a solid 5 minutes now.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215234/achievements-can-be-used-against-us-by-trolls :)

Answer (score 16):

The site hit hackernews. Something like 1000000 people are now voting on the question. Some are voting up, some are voting down. This is causing the vote spinner to go absolutely insane for you.

The best thing to do is to walk away from your computer. Go outside. Do not contribute to the problem.

<strike>whoa whoa whoa, I retract my previous statement based on the new behavior being witnessed now on this question ...</strike>

Comment: It's happening to my question too though and I didn't quite make hacker news.

Comment: Unless there are thousands of votes on that question, people just spammed the vote button and casted/retracted their votes constantly. I would have expected some kind of rate limiting system to kick in after 10 votes or so.

Comment: I still vote the best thing to do is to leave the computer ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand but I'm still at work...

Comment: *ahem* I also sometimes suggest a 2 martini lunch ...

Comment: Can you please add a link to hackernews

Comment: @Kermit https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8136279

Comment: viewed 38787 times... Considering that most of them cannot vote, and those that can may or not be voting, I think a million might be a little... toaster.

Comment: Fair enough Travis. If only there were a way to use large numbers to indicate unreasonably large values that I have no way to evaluate directly ...

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, it wasn't me on the SuperUser. I don't even have an account there.

Secondly, I was just testing on your question. *Testing it real hard!*

Thirdly, it's not a bug. You're able to vote up, then down, then vote up again as many times as you want *(unless you're rate limited, which would take a lot)* up until 5 minutes is up like ChrisF stated. Because votes are locked after 5 minutes, unless the post is edited.

So that can cause the bouncing around. All it takes is just 1 person to do that. But it gets even more crazy when multiple people are doing it.

Comment: Votes are locked 5 minutes after the first vote.

Comment: ...which would be similar to how votes work on much less important things (comments).

Comment: @ChrisF I think votes are locked if you let them untouched for 5 miutes. If you play up-and-down, then leave it on no vote, then again play and leave it on 0, you can do this all day long.

Comment: https://www.screenr.com/MYXN <-- There is no logical explanation.

Comment: @ChrisF I have verified that *ypercube*'s comment is correct. Apparently I've been clicking wildly on this posts' vote buttons for 9 minutes straight.

Comment: This is the correct answer - a particular user was just upvoting, then undoing the vote, over and over.  While this doesn't occur often, it's annoying to see in the logs.  Look for some vote throttling in the future.

Comment: darn @JarrodDixon, I was thinking about a feature request... :/

Comment: Excellent idea, @Jarrod and it will also block [possible trolling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215234/achievements-can-be-used-against-us-by-trolls) aimed at specific users.

Comment: It appears that some throttling has been implemented. Reported first by [@bjb](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2530520#2530520)

Comment: @JarrodDixon You need to throttle the accept/unaccept too! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230996/revision-body-missing#comment836478_230996