# Downvote appearing and disappearing repeatedly every few seconds?

Tags: support, voting

I'm wondering if there's some problem going on over on SO. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29795681/157247) is constantly vacillating between a score of 1 and 2 (as I write this) because a downvote keeps appearing and disappearing, every few seconds. It seems unlikely that a bunch of people are showing up, downvoting, then un-downvoting, and I would expect the system to prevent a single user from constantly doing so, so...

Refreshed the browser window etc. to allow for a confused browser.

Update: It seems to have stopped now. But the behavior continued for easily 2-4 minutes and across multiple refreshes, closing the window and reopening it, etc.

Comment: Someone was messing with you. Possible using a script.

Comment: Maybe someone attempting to give you more than one downvote on that post? "_Downvote_, ok. _Downvote again_, huh it not stick?, _Downvote_, ok now works. _Downvote again_, huh it not stick again???, _Downvote_, ok now works. _Downvote again_, huh it not stick again????? ...."

Comment: Looks like I have a bug in my troll script, it shouldn't have stopped... thanks for reporting...

Comment: @rene: LOL! ....

Comment: @Oded: I'm amazed the system allows that, but I just tried it (on a really old answer, hopefully the relevant user isn't around at the moment) and it let me downvote, un-downvote 30 times in a row. Wow.

Comment: @Mat: Good thought. I could see that if it were less frequently over minutes -- "huh? I thought I downvoted that" -- or frequently, but only across up to, say, 30 seconds, but not the frequency it was happening for as long as it was happening.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237580/244519 and there does appear to be a throttle now, it just takes a while to hit it still https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237580/question-points-bouncing-around/237583#comment791697_237583

Comment: @Roombatron5000: Thanks. If there's a throttle, it needs improvement. In my test above I was clicking roughly twice a second. There is exactly zero justification for doing that more than, say, six or seven times, even for the most indecisive of people. :-)