# Suspended users can unaccept answers via android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, account-suspension

See the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/230996/timeline) of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230996/revision-body-missing):

> [image]

Looks legit, right? But now see the profile of the [question OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael):

> [image]

Suspended for over a day now. The unaccept was done via the android app. This should not happen.

<sub>*Credits go nicael for letting me know of this, kudos!*</sub>

Comment: @Tim actually, I don't think he did that to get around the block, since he didn't try to exploit it further and informed us in chat about what he did. Finding such bugs are in his very core, he just can't resist it - and in the long run, it's good for SE.

Comment: @Tim couldn't upload images when posting the question (error message that can't reach imgur) probably due to IP change in the servers.

Comment: yeah, I got the same error. I'm also not getting real time notifications and updates, I have to refresh to see any changes (achievements etc). Realtime network questions are not updating either.

Comment: @Tim sockets are broken for me for long time so I don't bother mentioning this anymore, but uploading is a different matter. Feel free to start bug report for some free MSE rep. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next API build.

`/accept/undo` was missing the `IsSuspended` check.

Comment: So in case I get suspended I have until the next API build to unaccept this... ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You've had over 10 months to do it, what's one more build?