# Line between meta.stackexchange, meta.stackoverflow and stackoverflow.blog

Tags: discussion, meta

Recent [Joel's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) (or however you would like to call it) on MSO sparked up quite a bit of [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342480/should-time-to-take-a-stand-question-be-closed-moved) about *What does an [immigration executive order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_the_Nation_from_Foreign_Terrorist_Entry_into_the_United_States) have to do with Stack Overflow?* And we have concluded that it matters, to the company, or to the CEO, or to the world, or, well, the point is many people do care and SO does have a right to its own opinion.

However, [we still can't figure out whether MSO is indeed the appropriate place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342488/2363015) (refer to the comments). Is it a meta about *SO the site* or *SO the company*? Would that topic be more appropriate here, on MSE, since it has a wider audience and doesn't concern *SO the site* in particular, but rather the company and/or the whole network? Also, what's the role of the [official company blog](http://stackoverflow.blog) in that case?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290435/follow-up-on-stack-exchange-stack-overflow-name-change-announcement

Answer (score 3):

The Stack Overflow blog is the company blog to make announcements (like their name change, new investors, etc.) directed to the entire Stack Exchange community. The blog is used for everything that is not really open to discussion and are just 'executive' announcements (primarily one direction).

Meta Stack Exchange is just the big brother of Meta Stack Overflow (and all other child metas), so if a topic is allowed here on MSE, it probably is on MSO too. Unless the question is site-specific, a *meta* question could fit as good there as here. *meta* here refers to the inner working of the site(s), their rules and how we interact together.

Whether the question belongs here depends on whether the topic is allowed here and if the audience is the broader SE community or not. Since Joel has given not much information on his intended audience and the actual question he is asking we can't say if it fits here or not.

Comment: Also worth noting that up until about 4 years ago, [MSE wasn't really a useful thing, and MSO fielded all the network wide questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange?noredirect=1&lq=1). So you might notice even more fuzzying of the lines from users who were around prior to that split.