# Follow up on Stack Exchange => Stack Overflow name change announcement

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

There is a blog post from late 2015 titled [We're Changing Our Name (Back) to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) that reads:

> Here’s what’s changing:
>
> 1. As of today, our company will be known as Stack Overflow.
> 2. Our logo is different. But only a little.
> 3. Not one other damn thing.

What was the ultimate fate of this change? I can see that:

- The footer of https://stackoverflow.com/ reads "Stack Exchange, Inc."
- The [whois info for stackoverflow.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com) shows "Stack Exchange, Inc." as the registrar.
- The [wikipedia page for Stack Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) states the owner as "Stack Exchange, Inc." and appears to describe "Stack Overflow" as the site name only. The article does not contain the word "company".
- The [Stack Exchange about page](https://stackexchange.com/about) identifies "Stack Overflow" as a site name, although it does separate "Q&A network" and "Stack Overflow" on its right sidebar.
- The [Stack Overflow Blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/) contains "(C) 2017 Stack Overflow" (no corporate suffix).
- The [Stack Overflow about page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) identifies "The Stack Overflow Company".

Most parts of the network identify Stack Exchange, Inc., and public information on the internet does not identify Stack Overflow as a company. However, the Stack Overflow Blog as well as the SO About Page do contain references to it, although they seem to be isolated.

Can we get some follow up info to the above blog post? What's the deal with the "Stack Overflow" company name, and how does it officially fit into the "Stack Exchange, Inc." corporate structure?

This also serves as a follow-up to [this late 2015 post prompted by the blog announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266412/230261). At that point the path forward didn't seem to be set in stone yet, and some of the comments labelled it as more of a casual "rebranding" than a full-blown rename.

This is heavily related to the [Line between meta.stackexchange, meta.stackoverflow and stackoverflow.blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290430) post, which asks about the line of responsibility between various network sites, but I felt this question was different enough: This post concerns just the name change announcement and follow up, not the purpose of the individual sites.

Comment: Isn't Stack Overflow just their brand name?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm not sure; that's part of the question. :)

Comment: @Patrick I wouldn't say so, they explicitly say _Learn more about Stack Overflow **the company**_ (emphasis mine) in the subtitle for _About us_ link in the _help_ menu in the network header (uppermost part of the screen).

Comment: also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266410/how-to-refer-to-stack-exchange-the-company-after-its-rename-to-stack-overflow

Comment: Interesting tidbit: GitHub username is @StackExchange, full name is Stack Overflow

Comment: multiple personality disorder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Stack Exchange, Inc* is to *Stack Overflow* like *Richard Starkey, MBE* is to *Ringo Starr*.

To improve the analogy, imagine that prior to starting his music career, he also created "Richard Starkey network" of websites, and prefers to keep that name for the network.

Both names remain in use; the former on [legal documents](https://stackexchange.com/legal), the latter on marketing materials. There's also a spectrum of things between these. Some are closer to legal, like a footer with license terms. Some are closer to marketing, like "about our company" page. The blog is mostly a marketing effort, so "Stack Overflow" looks better on its pages and in its footer. Besides, it's unlikely that scrapers are clamoring for blog's content and need to be served notices from the legal department.

Comment: Ah, so more of a casual preference / marketing identity / [re-]rebrand, rather than an official corporate entity? If a person refers to the "Stack Overflow Company", what should that be interpreted to mean?

Comment: They refer to the company that prefers to be known as "Stack Overflow", whose legal name is "Stack Exchange". And perhaps they included "company" to differentiate it from Stack Overflow the website.